# How to write linq .join with expressions tree to do dynamic queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, expression

I Can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere...

The objective is to find a way to do linq .join() using Expression tree statements.

So... using [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join?view=netcore-3.1):

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public static void JoinEx1()
{
    Person magnus = new Person { Name = "Hedlund, Magnus" };
    Person terry = new Person { Name = "Adams, Terry" };
    Person charlotte = new Person { Name = "Weiss, Charlotte" };

 

   Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
    Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
    Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
    Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };


List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte };
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, daisy };

// Join the list of Person objects and the list of Pet objects
// to create a list of person-pet pairs where each element is
// an anonymous type that contains the name of pet and the name
// of the person that owns the pet.
var query = people.AsQueryable().Join(pets,
                person => person,
                pet => pet.Owner,
                (person, pet) =>
                    new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name });
```

Can anyone help me on how to do the .join() using [Expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries)?

Comment: [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) is very useful for this sort of thing - you can use `query.Expression.Dump()` to output the `Expression` tree created by the compiler and determine how to build it yourself. In this particular case, you are using an anonymous type which is a little bit tricky but can be handled using type inference and anonymous type templates.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at Predicate Builder: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Do you want to pass in the parameters as they are passed in to `Join`, including the result lambda, or do you want to build the key and result lambdas as well?

Comment: @NetMage, everything. I must create it from scratches. Parameters, variables, relation betwen them... couldn't yet see LINQPad, but will do.

Comment: @NetMage , Installed LINQPAD... still trying to understand it's tree output :) thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Queryable.Join` is a generic static method, it is easiest to use an extension method to lookup the `MethodInfo` for the one you need:

```
public static class TypeExt {
    public static MethodInfo GetMethod(this Type t, string methodName, int paramCount) =>
        t.GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.Name == methodName && mi.GetParameters().Length == paramCount).Single();
}
```

The `Join` method takes five parameters (extension methods pass the object they are applied to as the first parameter), so we will build them as `Expression`s one at a time. The five parameters are the `IQueryable<>`, the `IEnumerable<>` to join, the outer key selector lambda, the inner key selector lambda and the result selector lambda.

```
// Build Queryable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult> and use as query expression

// IQueryable<TOuter>
var arg0 = Expression.Constant(people.AsQueryable());

// IEnumerable<TInner>
var arg1 = Expression.Constant(pets);

// TOuter person
var arg2p = Expression.Parameter(people.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0], "person");
// also TKey person
// Expression<Func<TOuter,TKey>>: person => person
var arg2 = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(arg2p, arg2p));

// TInner pet
var arg3p = Expression.Parameter(pets.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0], "pet");
// TKey pet.Owner
var arg3body = Expression.Property(arg3p, "Owner");
// Expression<Func<TInner,TKey>>: pet => pet.Owner
var arg3 = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(arg3body, arg3p));

// TResult = typeof(new { string OwnerName , string Pet })
var anonymousType = (new { OwnerName = default(string), Pet = default(string) }).GetType();
// .ctor
var arg4Constructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors()[0];
// person.Name
var arg4PersonName = Expression.Property(arg2p, "Name");
// pet.Name
var arg4PetName = Expression.Property(arg3p, "Name");
var arg4Args = new[] { arg4PersonName, arg4PetName };
// new[] { .OwnerName, .Pet }
var arg4Members = anonymousType.GetProperties();
// new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name }
var arg4body = Expression.New(arg4Constructor, arg4Args, arg4Members);
// Expression<Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>>: (person,pet) => new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name }
var arg4 = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(arg4body, arg2p, arg3p));
```

Note: For complicated nested lambda closure reasons, each lambda is surrounded by `Expression.Quote` so the `Expression` compiler will know to return an `Expression` tree and not a delegate. In this example it makes no difference.

Now using the extension method you can lookup the `Join` you need to use, instantiate it from a generic method to the specific method for the types you are querying, and create the `Join` method call expression:

```
var joinGenericMI = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Join", 5);
var joinMI = joinGenericMI.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { arg2p.Type, arg3p.Type, arg2p.Type, anonymousType });
var qExpr = Expression.Call(joinMI, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

Finally, you can create an `IQueryable<>` with the `Expression`:

```
var q2 = people.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery(qExpr);
```

Comment: the joinGenericMI raised an error on 5, and I replaiced it with MethodInfo joinGenericMI = typeof(Queryable)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Join" && m.GetParameters().Length == 5)
            .First();

other than that, it did exactly what was created for. Thanks.

Comment: @DiogoAlmeida Interesting - what version of .Net are you using?

Comment: I have .net v4.8 installed (release 528040 in regedit). @NetMage

Comment: I have been trying this example for a couple days. The reference to "arg2.ReturnType" in your MakeGenericMethod call throws an error as UnaryExpression does not contain a return type. Any suggetions?

Comment: @RachelOstrander You are right, that is an error: it should be `arg2p.Type` (even though conceptually it is `arg2.ReturnType`, that isn't readily available due to the `Expression.Quote` around the lambda).