# Lambda expression to Expression<T> Tree (Slice 2 - Join)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, expression

How do you put an elephant into a refrigerator? You slice it... Sooo, how do you Translate a lambda Query to Expression tree? You slice it...

This is a serie of 3 slices of lambda expression to Expression tree.

Slice 1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693230/how-to-write-linq-join-with-expressions-tree-to-do-dynamic-queries), How to do .join() using Microsoft example.

Slice 2 (This Slice). Eager loading with diferent parameters from those used in Slice 1.

Slice 3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865724/lambda-expression-to-expressiont-tree-slice-3-how-to-end-the-query-with-whe), How to finish the Query with .where() and .Select().

In this Slice I am trying to convert the following query to Expression tree syntax:

```
IQueryable<A> As = db.A
                     .Join(
                           db.B,
                           _a => _a.bID,
                           _b => _b.ID,
                           (a, b) => new { a, b })
                     //The next two statements are going to next slice.
                     .Where(s=> s.b.Name == "xpto")
                     .Select(s => s.a);
```

In slice 1 I had:

Previous example of transformation:

```
var query = people.AsQueryable().Join(pets,
                person => person,
                pet => pet.Owner,
                (person, pet) =>
                    new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name });
```

That resulted in @NetMage answer, that did the trick with:

```
// Build Queryable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult> and use as query expression

// IQueryable<TOuter>
var arg0 = Expression.Constant(people.AsQueryable());

// IEnumerable<TInner>
var arg1 = Expression.Constant(pets);

// TOuter person
var arg2p = Expression.Parameter(people.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0], "person");
// also TKey person
// Expression<Func<TOuter,TKey>>: person => person
var arg2 = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(arg2p, arg2p));

// TInner pet
var arg3p = Expression.Parameter(pets.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0], "pet");
// TKey pet.Owner
var arg3body = Expression.Property(arg3p, "Owner");
// Expression<Func<TInner,TKey>>: pet => pet.Owner
var arg3 = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(arg3body, arg3p));

// TResult = typeof(new { string OwnerName , string Pet })
var anonymousType = (new { OwnerName = default(string), Pet = default(string) }).GetType();
// .ctor
var arg4Constructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors()[0];
// person.Name
var arg4PersonName = Expression.Property(arg2p, "Name");
// pet.Name
var arg4PetName = Expression.Property(arg3p, "Name");
var arg4Args = new[] { arg4PersonName, arg4PetName };
// new[] { .OwnerName, .Pet }
var arg4Members = anonymousType.GetProperties();
// new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name }
var arg4body = Expression.New(arg4Constructor, arg4Args, arg4Members);
// Expression<Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>>: (person,pet) => new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name }
var arg4 = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(arg4body, arg2p, arg3p));

var joinGenericMI = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Join", 5);
var joinMI = joinGenericMI.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { arg2p.Type, arg3p.Type, arg2.ReturnType, anonymousType });
var qExpr = Expression.Call(joinMI, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

For this slice, the following statement - presented in previous slice - needed to be changed:

```
// TResult = typeof(new { string OwnerName , string Pet })
    var anonymousType = (new { OwnerName = default(string), Pet = default(string) }).GetType();
```

@NetMage adapted it to generic A and B:

```
// TResult = typeof(new { A , B })
var anonymousType = (new { A = db.A.FirstOrDefault(), db.B = B.FirstOrDefault() }).GetType();
```

and

```
var arg4Constructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors()[0];
// person.Name
var arg4PersonName = Expression.Property(arg2p, "Name");
// pet.Name
var arg4PetName = Expression.Property(arg3p, "Name");
```

became (adapted to generic A and B):

```
// object A
var arg4A = arg2p;
// object B
var arg4B = arg3p;
```

Now it is needed to filter the result by b.Name and Select a (next Slice).

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right terminology, there is no expression tree in your code, or your previous question... Are you sure this is what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Comment: you are absolutly right. There is no Expression tree here... and that is exactly the problem... what would it be (probably beeing 3:30 a.m didn't help on delivering the question) :) @NetMage did a very good job in the previous question where there is a microsoft example of what is wanted. He gave a good answer and pointed to linqpad... but I'm having problems filling the gap between both cases. I didn't want to post his answer in this question, but maybe it would be good... thank for your comment.

Comment: I've written a [library](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString) which may help you. Add the NuGet package, add `using ExpressionTreeToString;`, then call `As.Expression.ToString("Factory methods", "C#");` to return a string with the factory methods needed to reproduce the given expression. Alternatively, you could install the [visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer) I've written, and [choose the factory methods formatter](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer/blob/master/formatter-switch.gif).

Comment: @ZevSpitz, really cool stuf there. Very cool indeed. Can I give you an input from user point of view for the libraries? If you could also do the inverse in visualizer or string - I mean: from an Linq expression (for ex.) , create the Expression tree - that would be freaking awesome.  P.S. Love the visualizer :)

Comment: In the previous coment:  "I mean: from an Linq expression (for ex.) , create the Expression tree in c# code"

Comment: Using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), you can create a lambda variable `Expression<Func<int,bool>> f = n => n % 2 == 0;` and then output the `Expression` tree `f.Dump();`

Comment: I'm actively learning how to use LinqPad (the basics and ExpressionTrees) :). Thanks for pointing the way. Unfortunately  I'm still not good - to say the least - at it X-)...

Comment: Responding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822237/lambda-expression-to-expression-tree-with-linq-join-and-where?noredirect=1#comment112888832_63822237), thanks for the suggestion. Do you mean parsing a string of C# code such as `"p => p.LastName == \"A\""` into an `Expression` object? Some kind of wrapper for the Roslyn compiler? And the debugged `Expression` could be replaced with the new `Expression`? I would ask you to open an issue, either on the visualizer or the library, and elaborate a little.

Comment: Also, note that `Queryable.Where` is an extension method, which means 1) it's a static method and has no instance, and 2) it takes two arguments: the `IQueryable<T>`, and the lambda expression. But if that is the case, this is probably a new question.

Comment: @Zev Spitz, I will open the sugestion on your library. About .where() being a new question it is probably a good idea. One for the .join(), one for the .where() and .select(), linking all, and making each one more SE and user friendly (this one is already kinda confusing with the edits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the return type from the `Join` method, do this:

```
// TResult = typeof(new { A , B })
var anonymousType = (new { A = db.A.FirstOrDefault(), db.B = B.FirstOrDefault() }).GetType();
```

You need to create an anonymous type where the member `A` has type `db.A` entity type. If you use e.g. `typeof(A)`, then you will have `A` with type `Type`, completely unrelated to the `Join`. (If you knew the entity type of `A`, you could just use `default` like I did: e.g. if `db.A` is `DbSet<AClass>` then use `A = default(AClass)`.)

Since you are not referencing any properties in the `Join` result, you just use the parameters:

```
// object A
var arg4A = arg2p;
// object B
var arg4B = arg3p;
```

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect your answer. Sooner than later i was stuck again, now in the .where(). I tryed to show in EDIT 2 what i've done (probably some rookie mistake :-/ ).

Comment: I have sliced this question in two. I'm playing with LinqPad (great, greaaat tool), but can't get to put the .Where() to work. Can you please check it, if you could? I'm actively trying to figure out the solution, but i'm not being capable of doing it, and at this moment you are the one with the answers. Thanks.